# Assigning a background color to a UITextField

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, uicolor

I have a main controller header with a color declaration

MainViewController.h

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> {
UIColor *myColor;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor *myColor;
@end
```

and an implementation with an initialization

MainViewController.m

```
@implementation MainViewController
@synthesize myColor;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.98 blue:0.8 alpha:1]; //initialization
}
```

Now I want to use this color in a method in MainViewController like this

```
- (void) myMethod {
myTextField.backgroundColor = myColor;
}
```

but but all my attempts are in vain. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Unless you use that color a lot, there's no need to store it, just use it in `myMethod`. How are you creating `myTextField`? Are you using Interface Builder? Did you link it to your IBOutlet?

Comment: Yes, I use this color a lot (I have 25 UITextField).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must send a retain to the color object you initialize :

```
myColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.98 blue:0.8 alpha:1] retain];
```

or set the property like so :

```
self.myColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0
                                green:0.98
                                 blue:0.8 alpha:1];
```

which, according to the property you declared, should retain it. The way you set the `backgroundColor` is ok.

Answer (score 0):

if u not synthesize the myTextfield then

```
    [myTextField setBackgroundColor:myColor];
```

if synthesize the myTextfield then

```
         self.myTextField.backgroundColor = myColor;
```